# The domain of cubic root

Tags: calculus, roots

The domain of cubic root and in general $(2n-1)$ th root is $\mathbb{R}$. But [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain%20of%20x%5E%281/3%29) says the domain of cubic root is all non-negative real numbers. Also Matlab return `0.5000 + 0.8660i` for `(-1)^(1/3)` and return `0.3969 + 0.6874i` for `(-0.5)^(1/3)` that have an imaginary part. Although Excel return `-1` and `-0.7937`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem. As Wolfram Alpha writes it returns the **principal cube root** (as does Matlab). And Wolfram Alpha hints that you can `Use the real‐valued root instead`.

There a three (complex) cubic roots for a number. If you look at the diagram for the input `(-1)^(1/3)` you see the principal root, its conjugate and your real root.

Comment: You should also probably mention that the n-th root of a number has n solutions.

Comment: Oh, I forgot! We can write $a^{1/n}$ as $f(x)=x^n-a=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The $n$-th root functions are [multivalued functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function), there are $n$ different function branches to pick from.

One does this because on that restriction the function is singlevalued and easier to work with (we have a naming problem here: a function with many values is a relation and not really a function).

In your case $n = 3$, there are three different ones. And your mentioned programs pick different ones.